# delphi tlist object method calling

Tags: delphi, tlist

all,

In Delphi, I created a simple class called T_Test (see below).

```
T_Test = class(TObject)

private

 F_Int : Integer;

public

  constructor Create(inInt: Integer);
  destructor Destroy; override;

  property Int: Integer read F_Int write F_Int;

  function showInt : String;


end;

constructor T_Test.Create(inInt: Integer);

 begin

  F_Int := inInt;

 end;


destructor T_Test.Destroy;

 begin

  self.Free;

 end;


function T_Test.showInt : String;

 var outputLine : String;


 begin

   result := IntToStr(Int);
   outputLine := result;
   Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(outputLine);

 end;
```

Then I have a procedure in which I want to make a TList of T_Test object and call the 
showInt method function on them.

I tried like this :

```
procedure testTlist;

 var

  a, b: T_Test;
  i : Integer;

 begin

  a := T_Test.Create(5);
  b := T_Test.Create(10);

 listTest := TList.Create;

 listTest.Add(a);
 listTest.Add(b);


 listTest[i].showInt;


end;
```

But I keep getting an an that says I have to use a Record, Object or Class Type on the 
call of 'listTest[i].showInt'

Does anyone know how to call this method ?

Comment: You currently don't destroy your objects. Just as well really since Self.Free will lead to unterminated recursion. Remove the destructor which you don't need, but call Free on your objects.

Answer (score 4):

Cast the listTest[i] pointer back to T_Test and then call its method:

```
T_Test(listTest[i]).showInt;
```

Alternatively, if available, use a templated TObjectList class to store T_Test instances directly.

Answer (score 2):

Martin's answer is correct. But it's worth noting that if you might be adding different classes to your list, a more robust fragment of code would be ...

```
var pMmember: pointer;

pMember := listTest[i];
if TObject( pMember) is T_Test then
  T_Test( pMember).ShowInt;
```

Martin's point about TObjectList is quiet correct. Another option to consider would be TList<T_Test>. David's comment about the error in your destructor is correct too.

I note that you did not initialise the value of i. So the fragment above is pretending you did. If you also wanted to check that the index variable was at a valid value, and not call ShowInt if it was invalid, then you could do something like this...

```
if (i >= 0) and (i < listTest.Count) and (TObject(listTest[i]) is T_Test) then
  T_Test(listTest[i]).ShowInt;
```

The above code fragment relies on short-circuit boolean evaluation.

Comment: well, the issue about the 'i' index is a copy paste error tbh. but thx anyway mentioning it

Comment: i have a question about the freeing of objects still.  when i have let's say 5000 elements in my list, what is the best way to free the memory of my list of elements ?  Is it not done automatically ?

Comment: If you use TObjectList instead of TList (recommended), then the default behaviour is that when a object is removed from the list, or the list is cleared, then the object is automatically destroyed.